# Por que al compilar un proyecto "viejo" en flutter marca el siguiente error ? Que tengo que hacer para solucionarlo?

Tags: flutter, dart

Mi flutter Doctor :
[image: Todo parece funcionar sin ningun problema]

Pero cuando ejecuto Flutter run 1 :
[image: Como puedo compilar mi programa?]

Comment: Flutter doctor es bastante claro. Ve al SDK de Android, encuentra el archivo `sdkmanager` y abre un terminal en esa carpeta. Luego ejecuta el comando `sdkmanager --install ...`  y el segundo comando que aparecen en la primera captura. Si aún tienes problemas, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/565115/edit) la pregunta con los nuevos problemas. También puedes intentar reinstalar Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, para aclarar el flutter doctor marca que falta un complemento de android pero no es tan necesario para el desarrollo del proyecto, principalmente por que se compila para windows, Bueno realmente lo que hice fue actualizar todas las dependencias del archivo .yaml algunas dependencias tienen problemas con las nuevas versiones de flutter.

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [ask] y [answer]. En la pregunta, pon el error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes, y difícilmente alguien con un problema similar llegue a tu pregunta si el contenido es solo imágenes. Además, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.